# Appending to a list gives 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list

My question was to make a python program that fills the main diagonal of a square matrix with its row number and the right to left diagonal with its column number. The rest of the elements of the matrix are initialized to the sum of indexes of the elements.

So I approached this problem with the following code but when ever I tried running it, it has given the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shinigami/prac5.py", line 21, in <module>
    a[i].append(p)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Please also Let me know if there is another way to make a 2D List in python and take input in it from the User!

```
a=[]
dimen=input('Enter the no of rows you want ? ')


for i in range(dimen):
    for j in range(dimen):
        i=int(i)
        j=int(j)
    #print('ENter the value for the',i+1,'row and',j+,'column')
    #p=input()
        if(j==0):
            if (j==i):
                a.append(i+1)
            else:
                a.append(i+j+2)
        else:
            if ((i+j)==(dimen-1)):
                a[i].append(j+1)
            else:
                p=i+j+2
                a[i].append(p)

for i in range(dimen):
    for j in range(dimen):
                i=int(i)
                j=int(j)
        print(" ",a[i][j])

    print("")
```

Comment: What is `a[i].append(j+1)` supposed to do? `a[i]` is an integer. You can't `append` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/shinigami/prac5.py", line 21, in a[i].append(p) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'`

Your variable `a` is a `list` of `int`egers. When you write `a[i].append(...)` you're trying to call an `append` method on an `int` type, which causes the error.

Writing `a.append(...)` is fine because `a` is a `list`, but as soon as you *index* into the `list`, you're dealing with with the numbers within the list, and they have no `append` method. For example:

```
>>> a = [i for i in range(5)]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.append(5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[2].append(6)   # won't work!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Simply make sure you're using the correct types. The logic in your code is currently very complicated, so you should simplify it.

> Also Let me know is their a another way to make a 2D LIST

You can use list comprehensions. For example:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> dim = 2     # take user input here
>>> matrix = [(i, j) for i in range(dim) for j in range(dim)]
>>> pp(matrix)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
#
# Index into the matrix as you normally would.
#
>>> matrix[1][0]
0
>>> matrix[1][1]
1
```

The above was tested using Python3, but you can adapt it to Python2 if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to initialize elements of the `a` array like this

```
if (j==i):
    a.append([i+1])
else:
    a.append([i+j+2])
```

Answer (score -2):

dimen is a string not an int
try to do this

```
dimen=int(input('Enter the no of rows you want ? '))
```

This will turn the input of the user into an int

Here is your fixed code:

```
a=[]
dimen=int(input('Enter the no of rows you want ? '))


for i in range(dimen):
    for j in range(dimen):
        i=int(i)
        j=int(j)
    #print('ENter the value for the',i+1,'row and',j+,'column')
    #p=input()
        if(j==0):
            if (j==i):
                a.append(i+1)
            else:
                a.append(i+j+2)
        else:
            if ((i+j)==(dimen-1)):
                a[i]=j+1
            else:
                p=i+j+2
                a[i]=p

for i in range(dimen):
    for j in range(dimen):
                i=int(i)
                j=int(j)
        print(" ",a[i][j])

    print("")
```

note that you cant append something into  a[i].You have to make a[i] equal to a value

Comment: This is not causing the error. (By the way: dimen *is* an integer. At least with Python 2.)

Comment: This is not the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Falko dimen is not an integer in Python 3

Comment: @cssGEEK: Yes, but according to the error message, the OP must have been using Python 2, since `range(dimen)` didn't raise an exception. ;)